# How do I make a thumbnail image from the canvas?

Tags: jquery, canvas

I have an HTML5 canvas, containing a few divs that contains a picture. I need to make this canvas an img and transfer it to an img element in another div (outside of the canvas) and resize it (the img element is smaller that the canvas).

Which means again, I basically want to "picture" my canvas with all of its content and put it into a smaller (than the canvas) img element.

[image: Here is a photo I made for you to understand better]

*Assuming the picture has the same width/height ratio as the canvas.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "thumbnail". It seems like your question boils down to "How can I create a thumbnail of a canvas?"

Comment: I am sorry i am not familiar with the exact phrase to describe this, that is why i added a photo for further explanation :)

Comment: How are you drawing a div on the canvas? Are you using [this complicated SVG approach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas), or is the div merely positioned over top of the canvas?

Comment: The div is not drawn on the canvas it is being append to a div containing the canvas. It is only appear on the canvas itself since the canvas fill the entire containing div.

Comment: I'm not sure, but actually content (like a `<div>`) inside the `<canvas>`-element is only allowed as a fallback: **"The contents of the canvas element, if any, are the element's fallback content."**, see: [w3.org: 4.8.11 The canvas element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-canvas-element)

Comment: It is not inside the canvas, it is inside the div containig the canvas , I guess what i need is a way to picture a part of the screen the canvas is streched on.Is there a way for a canvas to picture all of his pixels content?

Comment: @user1951341, [`HTMLCanvasElement#toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement#Methods)?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work??

```
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

    <img id="otherImage" src="..." />
    <img id="otherOtherImage" src="..." />

    <img id="savedPic" />

<form>
<input type="button" name="SavePic" value="Save Picture" onClick="savePic()">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
     function savePic(){
          var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
          if (canvas.getContext) {
               var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
               var iOne = document.getElementById("otherImage");
               var iTwo = document.getElementById("otherOtherImage");
               ctx.drawImage(iOne,0,0);
               ctx.drawImage(iTwo,50,50);

               var toSave = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
               var imageElement = document.getElementById("savedPic");  
               imageElement.src = toSave;

          }
}
</script>
```

So it's done in a 2 step process.  First draw the external images onto the canvas, then save the whole canvas to the 'thumbnail' image.

Comment: No, this doesn't work, because the OP wants to capture more than the state of the canvas. He also wants to capture `<div>`s that are positioned over the canvas. Your `<div>` here is only fallback content for browser that don't support canvas. The OP has `<div>`s that are next to the canvas, not actually within. (Your answer may have been written before he explained that in the comments.)

Comment: apsillers, your absolutely correct.  I will update my post, as I have one more idea.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and its working perfectly, it converts the whole canvas to image and download that image:

```
                const canvas = document.getElementById('main-canvas');
                const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                context.save();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';  
                context.fillStyle = 'white';
                context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.restore();
                var dataURL = context.canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = dataURL;
                a.download = "Thumbnail.png";
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                a.remove();
```